# Silverlight chart with behavior/bitmap image tooltip passthrough

Tags: charts, silverlight-4.0, tooltip

I have a chart showing bound data as tooltips and it works well.  I have added a magnifier(set of behaviors class) that captures a bitmap image at two times scale that shows in a circular area over the hover spot.  The tooltip does not display.  I have tried a custom tooltip service but cannot bind it to the behaviors.  I added the tooltip to the behavior class and got a tooltip and data but could not move it with the magnifier. It just sits in the middle and laughs.

I added a usercontrol "tooltip"-same issues, could not hook it to the magnifier behavior.  I know I can probably build a popup, but really wanted to just pass through the bitmap layer with the tootip.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I made it work- I added a canvas the size of the magnifier to the Grid containing the chart.  I added a times two sized bitmap layer that I clipped with an Ellipse, then added a Border to define the outline.  Finally I tied the Mouse to the Canvas for movement and made it hittest = true. Works great, the chart sees the mouse and I get a tooltip to go with the magnification.